# Beamer bold face using mathbf

Tags: beamer, bold, sans-serif

Beamer is not rendering bold fonts in math mode.  This is (somewhat) new behavior; in spring 2020 it was working as expected.  Previously, `$\mathbf{u}$` would yield a sans serif, bold face letter.  Below find a MWE.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

A vector could be expressed as $\mathbf{u} = \langle u_1, u_2, u_3 \rangle$.

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I cannot reproduce your problem with TeXlive 2021 under Linux: the u is bold.

Comment: @Gernot: Maybe I need a TeXLive update?  I'll check it out.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you see any warnings in the log file about fonts being substituted?

Comment: @Marijn: Yes.  The log file has a bunch of font warnings.  For instance:  


`LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape OT1/cmss/b/n undefined
(Font)              using OT1/cmss/m/n instead on input line 9.`


Anything in particular to look for?

Comment: The warning you posted is indeed relevant, it says c-omputer m-odern s-ans s-erif b-old n-ormal is missing and m-edium is substituted. That shouldn't happen - you could try `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` but even if that works you only avoid the problem instead of solving it. Which compiler do you use, pdflatex, xelatex, lualatex?

Comment: @marijn: I'm using pdflatex.  Seems like an upgrade to TeXLive 2021 would also solve the problem, however, my distribution of Fedora currently uses TeXLive 2020.  I guess I could upgrade manually....

Comment: A workaround that I actually tested with TeX Live 2020 is `$\text{\textbf{u}} = \langle etc`, (i.e., switch to text mode temporarily) but of course then you lose any math-like functionality that you might need.

Comment: See the above duplicate, that solution works also in TeX Live 2020 (the question was for 2019).

Comment: Alternatively `\usepackage{lmodern}` also works (which changes the font from Computer Modern to Latin Modern).